# Possible to dynamically fetch all entity relationships?

Tags: core-data, xcode9, swift4

Using Xcode 9 swift 4, is it possible to dynamically fetch all relationships for an entity? I can’t seem to find any examples that can get all relationship data from an entity without hard-coding relationship names.

**Edit**: I miss-explained my original question, fixed above. Adding my static code, which grabs an relationship data by name rather than dynamically.

*Disease* is an entity with a many-many relationship *own_pathology_organs* to another entity *Pathology_Organs*.

```
let pathology_organs = disease.own_pathology_organs?.allObjects as! [Pathology_Organs]
for pathology_organ in pathology_organs{
    pathologyArray.append(pathology_organ.name!)
}
```

Comment: A standard fetch request will return all attributes (albeit initially as faults).  In what way does this not meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I must have been tired last night. Question updated above. Basically I'm wondering if there is a way to loop through an entity to dynamically grab all relationship data, vs hard coding each relationship as in my code above.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, are you wanting to find all relationships on the `Disease` entity (of which `own_pathology_organs` is one you have hard-coded) or find all the values of the `name` attribute of the `Pathology_Organ` objects related to your `disease`?

Comment: The first one: all relationships on the `Disease` entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `entity` property of an NSManagedObject (or subclass) returns the `NSEntityDescription` for the object.  The entity description provides details about the entity, including a `relationshipsByName` property, which returns a dictionary, the keys of which are the names of the relationships (the corresponding values being `NSRelationshipDescription` objects which describe the relationship).  So to get a list of names of the relationships, you can use:

```
let relationshipNames = disease.entity.relationshipsByName.keys
```

From there you can use key value coding (`.value(forKey:)` and/or `value(forKeyPath:)`) to get the values from your object:

```
for relationshipName in relationshipNames {
    let keyPathToNameAttribute = relationshipName + ".name"
    let relatedObjects = disease.value(forKey:relationshipName)
    let relatedObjectNames = disease.value(forKeyPath:keyPathToNameAttribute)
}
```